# WHMC add jquery code to a template without modifying tpl file

Tags: whmcs

I would like to add some jquery code to a tpl file, say register.tpl.
But don't like to add it to register.tpl directly as upgradation on theme switch will be there.  Is there anyway to do it using module or add on?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "ClientAreaHeaderOutput" hook file and can do all jquery code in this hook file.

Like this:

function testHook(){
    $jquery = // jquery code here's

```
return $jquery;
```

}

add_hook('ClientAreaHeaderOutput',1,'testHook');